# Embedding a streams video in SharePoint without logging

Tags: sharepoint-online, video

I've uploaded a video to streams and embedded it within SharePoint. However, it requires a login to streams to show the video (even though we are logged in to sharepoint 365) as can be seen from the screen shot below :

[image]

Asking the users to login to a separate service to view the video would put people off from watching the video.  I would have thought office 365 and streams would be the same authentication.  How can i make it such?

the emedding code ive used is :

```
<br/>​​<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://web.microsoftstream.com/embed/video/videoIDgoeshere?autoplay=false&amp;showinfo=true" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is how it is designed. those videos are loading from stream so, user should have logged in before/active session in the same browser to the stream service as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.   That sucks. Why would they design them as separate logins when everything integrated.

Comment: Instead of using an Embed, use the [Stream web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-stream-web-part-b97fa87c-1337-4271-a059-17f0d2b26e8b).

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/portal-embed-video),only people authorized to see Stream content will be able to view it, even if it's embedded on another site.

1. Stream attempts to automatically determine the user's credentials if
   possible, however if the user is unknown, they will be prompted to
   sign in.
2. When the user is known, the permission settings are also maintained to ensure only 
   authorized users can watch, maintaining security and permissions.

Agree with Ganesh Sanap,we could use Microsoft Stream in SharePoint Online via a webpart refer to below articles:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/embed-video-sharepoint

https://sharepointmaven.com/what-is-microsoft-stream/